# Using Stripe.js in a Vue application to create a Stripe Card token not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, stripe-payments

I'm trying to use stripe.js within a Vue.js application to create a Stripe Card token that I can pass to a server for subscription processing.

Currently I'm just trying to create a new card with pre-set test values using this code in the `created()` method of this component:

```
this.stripeKey = process.env.VUE_APP_STRIPE_TOKEN_TEST;


this.stripe = require('stripe')(this.stripeKey);

this.cardExpiryMonth = 1;
this.cardExpiryYear = 2025;
const token = await this.stripe.tokens.create({
  card: {
    number: '4242424242424242',
    exp_month: 6,
    exp_year: 2024,
    cvc: '314',
  }
});

console.log(token)
```

When this component loads and this code is run, this error comes up:
[image]

Interestingly enough, when I monitor the network traffic Stripe.js appears to send the token creation request and receives a valid-looking token response:

[image]

Any ideas on making this stripe.js request successfully would be much appreciated, cheers!

Comment: You mentioned you're using `stripe.js`, but the function call you referenced seems to have [syntax](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_card?lang=node) matching that of `stripe-node`. If you are using `stripe-node` then it is concerning that you're able to see API requests made by it logged in your browser console. Those API requests are typically made with your secret Stripe API key, and that key being exposed in the browser's network logs is a concern. If the error you're showing doesn't prevent the request from completing successfully, are you able to use that result?

Comment: Ah you're right, I am using stripe-node.

I'm using a publishable Stripe API key for the frontend requests I'm making, not a secret Stripe API key so am not too concerned with that.

The error I am showing sadly does prevent the request from completing successfully, or else I would definitely just use the result.

Comment: For frontend code you should use [`stripe.js`](https://stripe.com/docs/js) instead of `stripe-node`. What are you trying to accomplish, or what guide are you trying to follow? Creating Tokens is a legacy approach to working with Stripe and one they don't recommend too often anymore. You may want to collect card details in your own UI and pass those values to Stripe, if card numbers touch your systems that greatly increases your [PCI compliance](https://stripe.com/guides/pci-compliance) burden.

Comment: @toby But isn't using the card token exactly to avoid sending sensitive card data from the frontend to the backend?

Comment: Apologies, I meant to say you may not want to collect card numbers in your own UI, because doing so puts more compliance burden on you. I would recommend using one of the Stripe provided UI components (Elements) to collect payment method details from your customer. Those are hosted by Stripe so card details never touch any of our systems. This guide walks through processing a payment using Stripe's Payment Element:  https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=elements